# How to solve generic ComboBox representation in a generic GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, celltemplate, autogeneratecolumn

I have a DataGrid in a user control (DataGridView). This usercontrol propagates a binding to DataGrid's ItemsSource from anywhere in the application and fills it with List of K.

For this example lets define clas for K that has some properties with custom attributes:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Enumeration(IsEnum=true, EnumerationType=typeof(MessageType))] //MessageType is enumeration and is consisted of values: 'Error', 'Warning' and 'Info'
    public MessageType MessageType { get; set; }

    [Enumeration(IsEnum=true, EnumerationType=typeof(FooType))] //FooType is enumeration and is consisted of values: 'Sweet' and 'Salty'
    public FooType FooType { get; set; }
 }
```

DataGrid has an event for autogenerating columns.

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Attribute attribute in (e.PropertyDescriptor as System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor).Attributes)
        {
            Utilities.EnumerationAttribute enumAttribute = attribute as Utilities.EnumerationAttribute;

            if (enumAttribute != null
                && enumAttribute.IsEnum)
            {
                DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

                templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["enumTemplate"];

                e.Column = templateColumn;
            }
        }
        e.Column.IsReadOnly = true;
   }
```

Resource for "enumTemplate" is defined in MergedDictionary as DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="enumTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

What I was intending to do is to set ItemsSource of each ComboBox the grid will generate with return value of Enum.GetNames(enumAttribute.EnumerationType) which is of type string[].

Now there is a lot of anonymity here and I don't know names of properties, their types or even the type of object this DataGrid would display during the run time.

I had several tries into this ... like defining a property DataSourcesList of type List> where NamedArray holds items to fill the combobox and a name of the property (from e.PropertyName) so that I know which of the NamedArray to use for combobox being generated ... something like:

```
 DataSourcesList.Add(new DataSourceWithMappedName<System.Object>() { MappedName = e.PropertyName, SourceList = Enum.GetNames(enumAttribute.EnumerationType) });
```

And then altering DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="enumTemplate">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <converters:IListToItemsSource x:Key="ilistToItemsSource"/>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataSourcesList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGridView}}, Converter={StaticResource ilistToItemsSource}, ConverterParameter={Binding somethingButAllInVaine}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

, but this can't be done since ConverterParameter is not a DependencyObject and can not be bound.

Maybe I should state that the same principle should be later used for binding collections and not just enums.

So please, can anyone help me with a solution to generic ComboBox representation in a generic GridView.

Tnx and happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it would be easier to set the `DataTemplate` up in code.  Start by defining the `datatemplate` and then setting the `ComboBox ItemSource Binding Source` to the `List of String` resulting from the `Enum.GetNames()`.

**Code Way**

```
        // Create template
        DataTemplate newTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory stackFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
        FrameworkElementFactory comboFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
        Binding newBinding = new Binding();
        newBinding.Source = Enum.GetNames(typeof(enumAttribute.EnumerationType));
        comboFactory.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, newBinding);
        stackFactory.AppendChild(comboFactory);
        newTemplate.VisualTree = stackFactory;

        // Set the template
        templateColumn.CellTemplate = newTemplate;
```

---

**XAML / Code Way***

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="EnumCollection"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="enumTemplate"> 
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumCollection}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Code (Make sure you set the `Collection Source`):

```
CollectionViewSource enumCollection = (CollectionViewSource)this.FindResource("EnumCollection");
enumCollection.Source =Enum.GetNames(typeof(enumAttribute.EnumerationType));
```

**Pure Xaml**

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EnumCollection"
                    MethodName="GetValues"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="YourEnum" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>

<DataTemplate x:Key="enumTemplate"> 
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumCollection}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Great solution. Does the right thing, not exactly as I intended but still works. Do you maybe know the XAML solution also or have any idea for it?